# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pyexpat: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using WINDOWS 7 - 32 bit.
Here's a screenshot of the problem that I am facing while creating a new project.

Unable to find any solution online. Badly need help!

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: The error raised while trying to install package management on your Python, try to do it manually instead by using `ensurepip` https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had `Python 3.8.1` installed, Don't know why but this version was causing the problem.

After uninstalling python and installing `Python 3.6.7`, it started working fine.
It took me a day to figure this out :)

Answer (score 6):

**Solved Issue**

```
ImportError DLL load failed The specified module could not be found
```

**Solution**:

No need to uninstall python in windows 7, you need to update MS visual C++, Follow these steps

1. Download: Microsoft visual c++ 2015 redistributable update 3
   from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587
2. Select system type whether 32bit or 64bit then install it.
3. Open command prompt type: `python`
4. Then import your library type: `import pyexpat`

Answer (score 5):

I came across this issue with `Python 3.8.3` and there is a simple solution

Within cmd, run:

```
conda init
```

Then Restart command prompt. Then run conda activate:

```
conda activate
```

After doing this, you can run jupyter notebook like this:

```
jupyter notebook
```

[image: shot]

Comment: this one worked for me, Thank you @Stevie, just make sure you would restart command prompt after "conda init"

Answer (score 0):

You could try to re-install pycharm and failing that python itself